# how to display telugu font on website

Tags: html, text

I have developed a website for local evening news paper which is in telugu language. I have used  to display and i'm using lekhini.org or branah.com website to generate telugu text by using general english typing. Everything is working fine and displaying perfectly if i'm using the generated text but my client using anu script manager and apple font, if they copied that text to website its not showing, instead it is showing some special characters. here is the screenshot i took, in the top line flash news it showing special characters which is a telugu text typed in quark express software using apple keyboard. remaining content was typed in lekhini.org website. please help me how to display the text written from apple font. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: 1. No one will be able to tell what is going on from such a low-res screenshot. 2. I understand you are obviously not a native english speaker, but you need to be a little clearer with what your asking. What is "Apple font"? Monaco? That being said, it's most likely due to you have the proper fonts and the client not, regardless of any other issue.

Comment: Do you have this in your `<head>`? `<meta charset=utf-8>`

Comment: apple is a name of one telugu font. telugu is an indian language. I want to display native language on html. I have used charset UTF-8 but still not working. Is there any supporting files that i should include on html page like jquery library to display native languages ?

Comment: @Explosion Pills yes i have kept the meta tag as you mentioned in head tag. if i removed the charset, the remaining content on the web page is not displaying properly like as the flash news script.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy the apple font or ANU fonts text directly to html as browsers do not support those fonts. Try to convert the ANU fonts to unicode font before using in html.
There are many converters online. You can look at india government converter at [www.cdac.in](http://www.cdac.in)